# Is there any reference made to the other sages in the future?

Tags: jak-and-daxter

In the first game there are 5 sages for each of the common eco types: green, blue, red, yellow, and dark. In the last 3 games in the series there only seems to be a sage of green eco, is there any in-universe mention of the other sages?